# how to get the max value of scrollY in scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I have a `scrollView` and a `LinearLayout` inside it. and in my app, i add some widget into my LinearLayout. I need to check if the scrollView is at the bottom. I use the following code to check it. but i need to know how to get the maximum value of scrollY:

```
ScrollPalyerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

            if (scrollY==`Max scrollY`)
               {
                  Log("tag","end of scrollView")
                }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer myself:

```
TheScrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight()-v.getHeight()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int currentY = v.getScrollY();
    if (scrollY > 100){
        Toast.makeText(this, "scroll at" + currentY, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```